Wp Elementor form submit to an email with custom Shortcode
I am trying to implement a WP Elementor form with a custom shortcode. I want to send the form submission to a dynamic email using a shortcode and here is the custom shortcode.
function agent_email_func(){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = get_userdata($id);
$html = $id->user_email;
return $html;
}
add_shortcode('agent_email','agent_email_func');

The above shortcode generates only an email address. For example, abc@gmail.com nothing else.
If I use static email without any shortcode, the form is submitted successfully.


Where do you get the $_GET['id'] from?

It's from the URL to get specific user details.
Based on the user ID, I am getting its email. If I access, www.abc.com//?id=2 I will get an email of user ID 2 and from www.abc.com//?id=5 I will get an email of user ID 5.
And I am getting its email in the custom code, mentioned above.
